# How I can get embedded attachments out of an Outlookmailitem? -> Get Attachments out of *.msg files

Tags: c#, compression, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, 7zip

at the moment I am delveoping an Outlook-addin (Outlook 2007) in C#, 
and I need to save the embedded attachments (usually images in BMP format).

I meen the attachments which are embedded by pasting ([CRTL]+[V])

When I try to save all attachments:

```
foreach (Outlook.Attachment a in mail.Attachments)
{

 a.SaveAsFile(path);

}
```

I've got a ComException (if the attachment is embedded else it will save it properly)

May someone help me - please ;-D

---

*EDIT*
At the moment I am thinking about a workaround.
I've tried to export the "OLE" object (I think it is ole) but it wasn't successful.

Now I am testing around with the *.msg export. If you open the *.msg file with 7zip fileexplorer you will get some files and folders. 
Inside an "*attachment*" folder you can find a "CONTENT" file, which is the embedded BMP file. But I am not able to access to *.msg with GZip (in .net).
I also tried the 7zip SDK [sample](http://7-zip.org/sdk.html) but I've got an error - "System error: Incorrect function".

If I try Gzip in .net - I'll get an exception "bad magic number" or something - so the problem is the filehead.

Could someone explain me how I can extract the files?

Comment: what exception you are getting

Comment: COMException occurred: Outlook can not open this file type (kind of - translated from German)